# Open project vs Project Libre

Tags: test-management, tools, development-process

Have  you experience  of  using  these and the  knowledge to make  a comparision between them for  the  suitability of  managing a  testing effort?

https://www.openproject.org

http://www.projectlibre.org/

On initial inspection they  both look promising but lack documentation

Comment: Closed as question was posted over on pm.stackexchange.com - prob a more relevant site.

Comment: why was this  downgraded? Project  managment tools are  not  part  of  testing are they?

Comment: It had been cross-posted to another site, it's generally considered preferable to post to just one of the stackexchange sites (we try to migrate to a better location if you get the wrong place to start with).

Answer (score 2):

This might get a more informed response over in Project Management https://pm.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Good suggestion. I'll ask the mods over there if they want to migrate it.